# Connection Failure with PHP and GMail IMAP

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I have looked at several tutorials and different explanations but although I have enabled imap in gmai, enabled the permission for insecure activities, my connection string is

```
imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', 'email', 'pwd')
```

and I have not activated the two-factor authentication I still have the same error.

> Cannot connect to Gmail: Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [ALERT]
> Please log in via your web browser

this is all the code

```
<?php
    
    /* Connecting Gmail server with IMAP */
    $connection = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', 'email', 'pwd') or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

    /* Search Emails having the specified keyword in the email subject */
    $emailData = imap_search($connection, 'SUBJECT "Article "');
    
    if (! empty($emailData)) {
        ?>
        <table>
        <?php
        foreach ($emailData as $emailIdent) {
            
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($connection, $emailIdent, 0);
            $message = imap_fetchbody($connection, $emailIdent, '1.1');
            $messageExcerpt = substr($message, 0, 150);
            $partialMessage = trim(quoted_printable_decode($messageExcerpt)); 
            $date = date("d F, Y", strtotime($overview[0]->date));
            ?>
            <tr>
                    <td style="width:15%;"><span class="column"><?php echo $overview[0]->from; ?></span></td>
                    <td class="content-div"><span class="column"><?php echo $overview[0]->subject; ?> - <?php echo $partialMessage; ?></span><span class="date"><?php echo $date; ?></span></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        } // End foreach
        ?>
        </table>
        <?php
    } // end if
    
    imap_close($connection);
}
?>
```

I don't understand why...

Comment: You shouldnt be trying to use login and password try [Xoauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol) or try an apps password.

Comment: Google specifically tries to limit access to their accounts to humans, and authorized software.  As DalmTo indicates, this is primarily done through an OAuth system.  However, for simpler software, they still supply the "App Specific Password" system.  Even then, sometimes they want to verify a human is involved, and require you to login through your browser on the same IP so they can verify.   If you are trying to write hosted software, you _will_ need to eventually implement OAUTH2, and php_imap is not really the library do it with.

Answer (score 0):

IMAP={imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX

$message = imap_fetchbody($connection, $emailIdent, 1);

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha  - go to this url and enable it.

Go to gmail
Top right - settings

See all settings - under - quick settings

Forwarding and pop/imap

Enable Imap - save changes

Next go to manage your google account - security

Less secure app access - On